# Color Spray vs. Small Earth Elementals

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The spell [Color Spray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/color-spray) causes up to three effects. Can you confirm what each effect does  against [Small Earth Elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-earth/small-earth-elemental)?

I know the mechanics of the spell. Pathfinder has a habit of tripping me up on things that I misremember from other systems. I'm looking to check that I haven't missed any of the small details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Small Earth Elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-earth/small-earth-elemental) are [Outsiders](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Outsider) ([Elementals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Elemental-Subtype), Earth, Extraplanar). Outside, Extraplanar and Earth appear to be irrelevant here.

[Color Spray](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-earth/small-earth-elemental)'s three effects are:
a) [Unconscious](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Unconscious) - I believe nothing they have protects against this effect.
b) [Blinded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded) - [Tremorsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Tremorsense-Ex-) could be used to negate the reflex save or fall over, assuming that they are **i)** on the ground, **ii)** able to use that ability and **iii)** Most importantly, your DM agrees ([YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary)).
Using RAW they still have to make a acrobatics check or fall over when they move more than half speed. Once in range of their target however [tremorsense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Tremorsense-Ex-) (if valid) lets them hit the target with a 50% miss chance due to being able to pinpoint the square. They still suffer all other effects of being [blinded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Blinded)
c) [Stunned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Stunned) - Elementals are immune

Comment: I think you mean acrobatics check or fall over?

Comment: +1 for teaching me that Elementals can be knocked unconscious. In fact, I learned they do not die at 0hp and they are actually subject to nonlethal damage.

Comment: You're welcome. I thought they were immune to the unconscious aspect as well. I kept thinking that they were in 3.5, but alas, still not immune to mind affected there either.

Answer (score 2):

A Small Earth Elemental is a 2HD creature, so it would normally get *"The creature is unconscious, blinded, and stunned for 2d4 rounds, then blinded and stunned for 1d4 rounds, and then stunned for 1 round."* but elementals are immune to the stunned effect so that would leave you with *"The creature is unconscious and blinded for 2d4 rounds, then blinded for 1d4 rounds."*